Early Warning System - Low Default Portfolio: Datasets in R
I'm currently working on some optimization of EWS for low-default portfolios.
For an article, I need to get some generic datasets for this - anyone an idea where i can find such datasets or how I can create them in R. I know the specifics of the portfolio, but until now i couldn't find a way to create realistic data.
I already created synthetic data but had the problem that my output didn't make any sense - for example i specified that the default rate should be around 1% over a timeperiod of 5 years, but it was above 50% (even though i used a pd migration matrix that should have prevented this). Also the creation of new loans or the handling of defaulted credit lines is not good.
Here are the specifics:

5000 credit lines
timeframe over 5 years (january 2019 to decemeber 2023)
Low default portfolio (only considering retail customers with historically low default rate)
Must include: Rating, Loan Amount, Origination Date, LTV, PD, EAD, stock market data (if applicable)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)  

# Initializing the Portfolio with varied issue dates
credits <- tibble(
  credit_id = 1:5000,
  issue_date = sample(seq.Date(from = as.Date('2015-01-01'), to = as.Date('2019-12-31'), by = "day"), 5000, replace = TRUE),
  loan_amount = runif(5000, min = 35000, max = 1250000),
  initial_rating = sample(c("AAA", "AA", "A", "BBB", "BB", "B", "CCC", "CC", "C", "D"), 5000, replace = TRUE),
  ead = runif(5000, min = 28000, max = 1000000),
  ltv_ratio = runif(5000, min = 0.5, max = 0.95),
  monthly_payment = runif(5000, 350, 25000),
  interest_rate = runif(5000, 0.02, 0.05),
  payment_status = sample(c("On Time", "Late", "Default"), 5000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.97, 0.02, 0.01)),
  days_past_payment = sample(c(0, 15, 31, 91), 5000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.97, 0.02, 0.005, 0.005)),
  new_loan = rep(FALSE, 5000), 
  observed_defaults = rep(0, 5000),
  current_rating = initial_rating, 
  default_status = rep(FALSE, 5000)
)

# Define transition probabilities
transition_probs <- list(
  AAA = c(AAA = 0.995, AA = 0.0049, A = 0.00009, Default = 0.00001),
  AA  = c(AA = 0.992, A = 0.007, BBB = 0.00099, Default = 0.00001),
  A   = c(A = 0.985, BBB = 0.014, BB = 0.0009, Default = 0.0001),
  BBB = c(BBB = 0.980, BB = 0.018, B = 0.0019, Default = 0.0001),
  BB  = c(BB = 0.970, B = 0.025, CCC = 0.0049, Default = 0.0001),
  B   = c(B = 0.960, CCC = 0.035, D = 0.004, Default = 0.001),
  CCC = c(CCC = 0.950, D = 0.045, Default = 0.005),
  CC  = c(CC = 0.920, D = 0.075, Default = 0.005),
  C   = c(C = 0.900, D = 0.090, Default = 0.01),
  D   = c(Default = 1.00)
)

# Function to update PD based on observed defaults
update_pd <- function(current_pd, observations) {
  adjusted_pd <- current_pd * (1 + (observations * 0.00002))
  min(adjusted_pd, 0.001)  # Ensuring PD does not exceed 1%
}

# Simulate transitions function
simulate_transition <- function(rating, observed_defaults) {
  if (rating == "Default") return("Default")
  probs <- transition_probs[[rating]]
  probs["Default"] <- update_pd(probs["Default"], observed_defaults)
  new_rating <- sample(names(probs), 1, prob = probs, replace = TRUE)
  new_rating
}

# Running the simulation over 48 months
for (month in 1:48) {
  credits <- credits %>%
    mutate(
      current_rating = map2_chr(current_rating, observed_defaults, simulate_transition),
      payment_status = case_when(
        days_past_payment <= 14 ~ "On Time",
        days_past_payment > 14 & days_past_payment <= 30 ~ "Late",
        days_past_payment > 90 ~ "Default",
        TRUE ~ payment_status
      ),
      default_status = current_rating == "Default",
      observed_defaults = if_else(default_status, observed_defaults + 1, observed_defaults),
      new_loan = default_status
    )
}

# Recalculating portfolio statistics after simulation
portfolio_stats <- credits %>%
  summarise(
    total_loans = n(),
    avg_loan_amount = mean(loan_amount),
    avg_interest_rate = mean(interest_rate),
    avg_ltv_ratio = mean(ltv_ratio),
    total_defaulted_loans = sum(default_status),
    default_rate = mean(as.numeric(default_status)),
    new_loans_issued = sum(new_loan)
  )

print(portfolio_stats)

